# ¿Cómo añadir approval en Azure DevOps a un pipeline YML?

Tags: pipeline, yml, devops

Estoy intentado añadir un approval a un pipeline de Azure DevOps que tengo creado en formato YML.

Para ello he visto que hace falta crear una variable "environment" en la cual añades aquí los aprobadores. Ya tengo creado este recurso necesario.

Mi problema es a la hora de añadir este environment, ya que recibo un error el cual dice:

> Unexpected value 'environment'

He probado a añadirlo en el YML de esta forma:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: xxx
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/xxx
    name: xxxx
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: xxxxxxxx
  pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016
  environment: 'Preproductive environments approvals'
  steps:
[...]
```

Además he visto que hay una tarea la cual replica este tipo de aprobaciones:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

> Job Job_1: Step  references task 'ManualValidation' at version '0.179.0' which is not valid for the given job target.

¿Os habéis topado con este error? Desconozco de que otra forma puedo implementar una validación o approval a los YML pipelines de DevOps.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a la que llegué fue la siguiente:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: xxx
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/xxx
    name: xxxx
jobs:
- deployment: deployment_1
  displayName: xxxxxxxx
  pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016
  environment: 'Preproductive environments approvals'
  steps:
[...]
```

Fue tan sencillo como cambiar lo que anteriormente indicaba como JOB a DEPLOYMENT. De esta forma si te deja integrar el environment y no muestra ningún tipo de error en las diferentes tareas que hay a lo largo del YML.

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso te falta definir el task como lo muestra el siguiente código

```
jobs:
- job: waitForValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation
  pool: server
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
  
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
    env: 
            
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: |
        test@test.com
        example@example.com
      instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
      onTimeout: 'resume'
```